# How to prevent Autodiscover to on-premises Exchange

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365, autodiscover

We have migrated a client from @example.co.uk and on-premises Exchange Server 2010 to @example.com and Office 365.

We are keeping the old Exchange server running for the time being in case any further data needs to be migrated.

We need to prevent AD domain-connected PCs' email apps (Microsoft Outlook, etc) from Autodiscovering to the old Exchange server. Thus far, I have done the following which hasn't worked:

1. Used EMS to set the CAS' Autodiscover service internal URI to null.
2. Used ADSI Edit to delete `CN=%Exchange server hostname%,CN=Autodiscover,CN=Protocols,CN=%Exchange server hostname%,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=%AD DS NetBIOS domain name%,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=%AD DS DNS middle-level domain name%,DC=%AD DS DNS top-level domain name%`.
3. Used AD UC to reconfigure an AD user account clearing the attributes `homeMDB` and `homeMTA`

Ideally, I don't want to:

1. Disable the Exchange Windows services.
2. Disable the Exchange user mailboxes.
3. Create registry entries defining the Autodiscover behavior (excluding SCP lookup, etc) on the clients.
4. Delete the IIS virtual directories.

What has to be done to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Option 1:***

There are multiple "configuration" options which you can perform which depends on your environment and on your clients (e.g. MS Office for MAC or Windows).

For example if you wish to [disable the AutoDiscovery on a MAC you can follow the howto here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/275-disable-autodiscovery-for-microsoft-office-for-mac.html).

[On windows you can finetune autodiscovery](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/267-speed-up-the-exchange-outlook-autodiscovery-process.html) via:

- PreferLocalXML
- ExcludeHttpRedirect
- ExcludeHttpsAutodiscoverDomain
- ExcludeHttpsRootDomain
- ExcludeScpLookup
- ExcludeSrvRecord
- ExcludeLastKnownGoodURL (only applies to Outlook 2010 version 14.0.7140.5001 and later versions)
- ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint (only applies to Outlook 2016 version 16.0.6741.2017 and later versions)

**Conclusion:**

I think "ExcludeScpLookup" is what you need here at least for Microsoft Office for Windows. You can find more infos [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/267-speed-up-the-exchange-outlook-autodiscovery-process.html) for the finetuning if needed.

***Option 2*** (but wouldn´t be a good one in my eyes):

You might try to point the internal autodiscovery settings to Exchange Online, you only need to adjust the following so that it fits your config:

```
Set-ClientAccessService -Identity "exch01" -AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri "https://mbx01.contoso.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml"
```

and

```
Set-AutodiscoverVirtualDirectory -Identity "exch01\Autodiscover (Default Web Site)" -InternalUrl https://excashlb.int.contoso.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml -ExternalUrl https://oaw.contoso.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
```

Then you might need to wait until it is replicated in your environment.

Comment: Is that the only option? As I said, I'd prefer to not create registry values on the clients / I'd prefer to resolve this from the server side. Thanks.

Comment: you might try to use option2, but its not designed to do that this way.

Comment: This answer was a Godsend.  We have been struggling for days to determine why Outlook 2016 suddenly decided it was going to just assume we wanted to connect to Office 365 and give us no options for connecting on-prem